# How do I find/replace text in a default value's calculated field?

Tags: list, default-value

I am attempting to set the default value of the *Title* item in a list so that it is more informative -- I have the *Title* field "hidden" from the user, but my company's workflow utilizes *Title* in workflow emails.

I want the title to contain the submitter's **Display Name**.  I have seen the `=[Me]` function but that returns the entire `DOMAIN\username` which is really ugly in my case.

If the **Display Name** isn't possible am I able to use something like a `REPLACE` function to at least remove the `DOMAIN\` from the string (so that just the user name remains)?

I've tried to do simply:

```
=REPLACE([Me],"DOMAIN\","")
```

But I get a syntax error.

Any ideas?

Comment: You may find this calculated column quick reference "Cheat Sheet" useful - http://blog.pentalogic.net/2011/05/sharepoint-calculated-column-cheat-sheet/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb862071.aspx) is a good reference on calculated columns.

I've found the easiest way (for me) to get user information is using [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com) and jQuery and setting the field value on item submission.  With SPServices [SPGetCurrentUser](http://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=%24%28%29.SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser&referringTitle=Documentation) operation, you can get various properties when they're filling out the form and put that into the hidden title field right away.

Comment: That SPServices looks interesting but is probably a little more intense than what I was looking for ... anyhow, I was able to use this `=RIGHT(Me,LEN(Me)-14)` and it is working great (or as good as I can hope without really getting into it).  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The [REPLACE function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/replace-function-HA001161055.aspx) takes 4 parameters, so you would need to write it like this:

```
=REPLACE([Me],FIND("DOMAIN\",[Me]),LEN("DOMAIN\"),"")
```

EDIT: For the default value of a column, [Me] is fine.

<strike>However, you cannot use [Me] in a calculated column, so this will not work either. And, from your description it sounds like you want the user that created the list item, not the current user. So, then you would want to use [Created By]. Unfortunately, you cannot use this in a calculated column either.</strike>

Instead, you can create a workflow in SharePoint Designer that executes when an item is added. In your workflow, you can get the current user and update the Title field with that value.

Comment: Apparently the OP is talking about a calculated value in a text column, not a calculated column. In this case [Me] is allowed.

Comment: Ah, now the question makes sense. I missed the words "set the default value". Thanks.

Comment: I don't have access to SharePoint designer - would have to talk with IS to get that implemented ... but, I appreciate your insight on the `REPLACE` function.  I'm sure to need that soon.  Thanks!

Comment: =REPLACE([Me],FIND("DOMAIN\",[Me]),LEN("DOMAIN\"),"") is working for me...Thanks guys.